# Showing content using .innerHTML after AJAX success

Tags: php, ajax

Newbie to forms here, I tried to figure this one out the whole day and just can't seem to get it working properly.

I have a simple contact form setup. The submission works but the "success message" that is supposed to show, doesn't.

It shows the word "success" but doesn't actually add what I told it to add.

Here is the markup for the form including the script:

```
<script>

function _(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

function submitForm() {
    _("mybtn").disabled = true;
    _("status").innerHTML = 'Your message is being sent';
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("n", _("n").value);
    formdata.append("e", _("e").value);
    formdata.append("m", _("m").value);
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open("POST", "email_form.php");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
            if (ajax.responseText == "success") {
                _("my_form").innerHTML = '<h2>Thanks ' + _("n").value + ', your message has been sent.</h2>';
            } else {
                _("status").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                _("mybtn").disabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
    ajax.send(formdata);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="mc-form">

<form id="my_form" onsubmit="submitForm(); return false;">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputNormal">Name</label>
    <input id="n" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required />
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputNormal">Email</label>
    <input id="e" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required/>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputWarning">Message</label>
    <textarea id="m" rows="10" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
</div>

<input id="mybtn" type="submit" value="Submit Form"> <span id="status"></span>
</form>

</div>
```

And here is the php that processes the email:

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST['n']) && isset($_POST['e']) && isset($_POST['m']) ){
$n = $_POST['n'];
$e = $_POST['e'];
$m = nl2br($_POST['m']);
$to = "admin@martinconde.com";  
$from = $e;
$subject = 'Contact Form Message';
$message = '<b>Name:</b> '.$n.' <br><b>Email:</b> '.$e.' <p>'.$m.'</p>';
$headers = "From: $from\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
if( mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ){
    echo "success";
} else {
    echo "The server failed to send the message. Please try again later.";
}
}
?>
```

Any pointers would be highly appreciated since I am about to pull my hair out here ;)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code works for me. Not sure what is wrong. Are you sure you have a file called `email_form.php` and are running on a system that can make use of `php`?

Comment: Yep filenames are correct and the email also arrives in my inbox so all of that works just the success message won't show for some reason.

Comment: Can you also check if the succes message is not hiding behind your form. For example with browser console. Might be a lay-out issue here.

Comment: Could you also try to add `if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) { ... console.log(ajax.responseText) ... ` to see what the value of `ajax.responseText` is in your browser console.

Comment: @LarsMertens Checked but its not hidden behind anything, its nowhere to be found in the markup. I added the log and it just showed "success" in the console so somehow it is taking it as a string instead of the state of the function.

Comment: Can you also check if it goes inside the success if statement by for example putting a console.log there `if (ajax.responseText == "success") { console.log("test") }`

Comment: When I try, all I get is "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token else". Not really sure how that is happening damn I should get a grip on this stuff..

Comment: Yes that is because probably you didn't close or open one of the `{ ( )  }`  brackets correctly now or add `; after console.log("test");`. Can you answer my previous question when you resolved the brackets or semicolumn issue.

Comment: I added it exactly as you sent it and inside of atom I am not getting any errors either: if (ajax.responseText == "success") { console.log("test") }

Comment: Are you getting a message `test` in your console? If not you simply have to remove the `if (ajax.responseText == "success") { ... }` statement and you're ready to go. `ajax.status == 200` already is enough data to determine the post completed succesfully. If you get a message `test` I could give you more information.

Comment: Yes I do get "test" output in the console now :)

Comment: This means that the post will go through all your if statements and means that the function is implemented correctly. Now I can think of 2 things why `_("my_form").innerHTML = '<h2>Thanks ' + _("n").value + ', your message has been sent.</h2>';` isn't working. 1. You have 2 divs or more with id `my_form` or `formdata.append("n", _("n").value);` value is invalid.

Comment: Gotta be the second one then since the form is the only thing left in the document so defenitely no double use of the id. I will keep checking on fixing that up then. Thanks a lot for all your help, really appreciate it! :)

Comment: No problem :) You could also extend your question now with the input you are trying to fill in the form and maybe the output by `_("n").value`. You will probably find a way to fix the issue now.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> if (ajax.responseText == "success") {
> ```

You test to see if the response is `"success"`.

> ```
>    _("my_form").innerHTML = '<h2>Thanks ' + _("n").value + ', your message has been sent.</h2>';
> ```

If it was, then you would see this message.

Since you don't see that message, the response cannot be `"success"`.

```
} else {
    _("status").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
```

So this code runs and the content of the message is added to the page.

There you can see that it is *success*.

This means that the string must be `" success"`, `"success "`, `"success\n"` or similar.

i.e. there is additional whitespace which you can't see by glancing at the rendered HTML.

---

You need to either:

- Change your test so it looks for success *within* the string *or*
- Fix the PHP so it doesn't output additional whitespace

Comment: Hope its not too much to ask but could you please elaborate on either of your proposed solutions? ;)  I checked for any whitespaces and even deleted and rewrote it just to make sure.

Answer (score -1):

I have copied your files and are working for me (check if you have saved you files). In any case I would check the response codes from server, because if there is an unexpected output the form is going to fail. Maybe its printing "success\n" with new line at the end and for that reason its failing.

```
// in email_form.php

// if successfull
http_response_code (200)
// if fails 500 or another error code.
http_response_code (500)

// In html

if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
  _("my_form").innerHTML = '<h2>Thanks ' + _("n").value + ', your...';
}
else {
   _("status").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
   _("mybtn").disabled = false;
}
```